# How to rename a document property in Cosmos DB?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

Is it possible to rename a property like in MongoDB, using C# SDK or migration tool?

I didn’t see any example about it

Comment: Have you tried reading+modifying+replacing the document in question?

Comment: Yes.If I read/modify/replace the old property Will still be stored

Answer (score 3):

DocumentDB is schemaless. There is no structure defined outside documents themselves so each document has their own schema. Hence you cannot rename a property outside of your documents themselves.

What you can and should do, is to fix documents which you consider having wrong schema by updating them. Query docs which have the wrongly named property, rename the property in the documents with you application logic, and update them to DocumentDB collection.

> Yes.If I read/modify/replace the old property Will still be stored

I can only assume this must be some mishap in your application logic. If not, then you should provide a minimal verifiable repro case.

Comment: Ok but if I have to rename it I should add another property in my C# class, mantains the old property in order to read the old values, set the old value in the new property and then save the document. Then I should remove the old property and save the document. If I have tons of documents it should takes a lot of times (and money).. They should add a rename fuction like in Mongo